# Is there a way to put a border around kivy BoxLayouts?

Tags: user-interface, kivy

I am designing a main menu for an app that i am creating, but i cant seem to figure out how to border a boxlayout in kivy, is there a way to do this? If so could someone help. I have tried to use a canvas.before and bordering the rectangle but that doesn't work.

```
<MainMenuWindow>:
    id: Main_Menu_window  ## setting the id to Login_window

    BoxLayout: ## whole screen
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        BoxLayout: ## left hand side 1/3
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                Line:
                    width:
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

            orientation: 'vertical' ## setting orientation of the screen to vertical
            size_hint_x: 1/3 ## setting size of box to 1/3 of the screen
            canvas.before:
                Color: ## just for debugging reasons
                    rgba: (255/255,255/255,255/255, 1)  ## setting colour
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size  ## setting size to the size of the box layout
                    pos: self.pos  ## setting position to the position of the box layout
```

Comment: What happens if you change the `rgba` to `1,0,0,1`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson this does not do anything. I dont think the canvas.before works at all here. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson is this any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BoxLayout` tries to use all its available space by allocating a share to each child. Since your inside `BoxLayout` is the only child of the outside `BoxLayout`, it will be allocated the entire space of the outside `BoxLayout`. So, you can control the size of your inner `BoxLayout` either by adjusting the size of the outer `BoxLayout`, or by explicitly setting the `size` of the inner `BoxLayout` (with `size_hint: None, None`).

So, here is one way to get the inner `BoxLayout` to one third the screen width:

```
<MainMenuWindow>:
    id: Main_Menu_window  ## setting the id to Login_window

    BoxLayout: ## whole screen
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        BoxLayout: ## left hand side 1/3
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
                Line:
                    width: 20
                    rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

            orientation: 'vertical' ## setting orientation of the screen to vertical
        Label:  ## middle third
            text: 'Abba'
        Label:  ## right third
            text: 'Dabba'
```